# Вывести на экран слова что начинаются с определенных 2 букв

Tags: c, строки

Строка состоит с определенного кол-ва слов и знаков пунктуации. Вывести на экран все слова которые начинаются заданным с клавиатуры сочетанием 2 букв.

Вот что у меня есть:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "apple apl lpa lpl app";

    char *pch = strtok(str, " ,."); 

    char str2[] = "ap";

    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
        if (strncmp(pch, str2,2)==0) printf("\n%s", pch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Выводит только первые слова

Comment: А в Debug-ере вы не смотрели что у вас в цикле происходит?

Comment: оно крашится, я не понимаю

Comment: А в каком месте и с какой ошибкой?

Comment: В цикле поменяйте местами первую и вторую строку.

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте местами строки в цикле. У вас в какой-то момент `pch` становиться равным `NULL` и вы этот `NULL` передаете функции `strncmp`. Из-за этого крашится.